# glmnet MatLab -

Tags: matlab, glmnet

I am trying to use `glmnet` package for MatLab. The glmnet works fine, but when trying to use `cvglmnet` (which is another function from the package), MatLab gives a "catastrophic" error which requires me to close it. It has something to do with a MEX file it is calling. I copied the whole error message below.
Any help is appreciated.

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.10552-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Mon Jul 06 17:28:49 2015
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1    : NVIDIA ( 0x10de ) NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M Version 9.18.13.4752
  Graphics card 2    : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 Version 10.18.10.3308
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b
  MATLAB Version     : 8.4.0.150421 (R2014b)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Single Language
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Software OpenGL    : 0
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 000000000402e7f0  RDX = 000000000402e8f0
  RSP = 000000000402cd08  RBP = 000000000402e8f0
  RSI = 0000000078ab6550  RDI = 000000000402e7f0

   R8 = 000000000402db10   R9 = 000000000402e7f0
  R10 = 0000000000000000  R11 = 000000000402e8f0
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 000000000402e8f0  R15 = 000000000402e7f0

  RIP = 00000000fe160b03  EFL = 00010286

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000000fe160b03 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmx.dll+00396035 MXGETPR+00000003
[  1] 0x00007ffee4d619dc C:\Users\Marcelo\Desktop\Marcelo\PUC\Mestrado\Dissertação\Instrument Selection\glmnet_matlab\glmnetMex.mexw64+00006620 MEXFUNCTION+00002524
[  2] 0x00000000fc5f36f0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00079600 mexRunMexFile+00000112
[  3] 0x00000000fc5f2762 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00075618 inSwapMexfileReader+00000690
[  4] 0x00000000fc5f2248 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00074312 mexUnlock+00006008
[  5] 0x0000000004a805e3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067043 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000659
[  6] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[  7] 0x0000000004e62b2f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00273199 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00017071
[  8] 0x0000000004e640c0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00278720 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00022592
[  9] 0x0000000004e61b4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00269135 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00013007
[ 10] 0x0000000004e61ab1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00268977 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00012849
[ 11] 0x0000000004e8406f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00409711 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00098591
[ 12] 0x0000000004e827af C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00403375 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00092255
[ 13] 0x0000000004e81359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00398169 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00087049
[ 14] 0x0000000004a805e3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067043 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000659
[ 15] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 16] 0x0000000004e62b2f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00273199 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00017071
[ 17] 0x0000000004e640c0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00278720 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00022592
[ 18] 0x0000000004e61b4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00269135 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00013007
[ 19] 0x0000000004e61ab1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00268977 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00012849
[ 20] 0x0000000004e8406f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00409711 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00098591
[ 21] 0x0000000004e827af C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00403375 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00092255
[ 22] 0x0000000004e81359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00398169 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00087049
[ 23] 0x0000000004a805e3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067043 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000659
[ 24] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 25] 0x0000000004e62b2f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00273199 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00017071
[ 26] 0x0000000004e640c0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00278720 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00022592
[ 27] 0x0000000004e61b4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00269135 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00013007
[ 28] 0x0000000004e61ab1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00268977 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00012849
[ 29] 0x0000000004e8406f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00409711 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00098591
[ 30] 0x0000000004e827af C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00403375 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00092255
[ 31] 0x0000000004e81359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00398169 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00087049
[ 32] 0x0000000004a805e3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067043 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000659
[ 33] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 34] 0x0000000004e3b606 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00112134 MathWorks::MException::IMExceptionData::IMExceptionData+00037094
[ 35] 0x0000000004e3aa20 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00109088 MathWorks::MException::IMExceptionData::IMExceptionData+00034048
[ 36] 0x0000000004e39219 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00102937 MathWorks::MException::IMExceptionData::IMExceptionData+00027897
[ 37] 0x0000000004e38de5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00101861 MathWorks::MException::IMExceptionData::IMExceptionData+00026821
[ 38] 0x0000000004e8b708 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00440072 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00128952
[ 39] 0x0000000004e63ea5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00278181 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00022053
[ 40] 0x0000000004e61b4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00269135 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00013007
[ 41] 0x0000000004e61ab1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00268977 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00012849
[ 42] 0x0000000004e8406f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00409711 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00098591
[ 43] 0x0000000004e827af C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00403375 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00092255
[ 44] 0x0000000004e81359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00398169 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00087049
[ 45] 0x0000000004a807a4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067492 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001108
[ 46] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 47] 0x0000000004e62b2f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00273199 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00017071
[ 48] 0x0000000004f4b6f7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01226487 inFullEvalFcn+00011159
[ 49] 0x0000000004e65592 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00284050 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00027922
[ 50] 0x0000000004e61b4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00269135 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00013007
[ 51] 0x0000000004e61ab1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00268977 inGetNameInSymbolTable+00012849
[ 52] 0x0000000004e8406f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00409711 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00098591
[ 53] 0x0000000004e827af C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00403375 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00092255
[ 54] 0x0000000004e81359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00398169 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00087049
[ 55] 0x0000000004a807a4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00067492 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001108
[ 56] 0x0000000004a80aee C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00068334 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 57] 0x0000000004eb4a88 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608904 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00297784
[ 58] 0x0000000004eb4a04 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608772 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00297652
[ 59] 0x0000000004eb49c5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608709 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00297589
[ 60] 0x0000000004eb4992 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608658 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00297538
[ 61] 0x0000000004eb4947 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608583 inPathNotification::function_delete_notification+00297463
[ 62] 0x0000000004e2d69d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00054941 inEvalExp+00001309
[ 63] 0x0000000004f5525d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01266269 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000285
[ 64] 0x0000000004f55181 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01266049 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 65] 0x00000000fb5fe31d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00058141 mnGetPrompt+00001517
[ 66] 0x00000000fb5fed09 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00060681 mnParser+00000745
[ 67] 0x00000000fd0dd834   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00383028 mcrInstance::mnParser_on_interpreter_thread+00000036
[ 68] 0x00000000fd0a68e7   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00157927 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00019751
[ 69] 0x00000000fd0a6923   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00157987 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00019811
[ 70] 0x00000000fd0a7121   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00160033 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00021857
[ 71] 0x00000000fab5d3a6   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00512934 UIW_AttachThreadInput+00001270
[ 72] 0x00000000fab5cc35   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00511029 wsd_to_MSW+00004373
[ 73] 0x00000000fab5ccb9   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00511161 wsd_to_MSW+00004505
[ 74] 0x00007fff0f5108ca                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00592074 BroadcastSystemMessageExA+00000586
[ 75] 0x00007fff0f482e1f                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00011807 IsWindow+00000367
[ 76] 0x00007fff0f482e96                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00011926 IsWindow+00000486
[ 77] 0x00007fff0f693034                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00602164 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000036
[ 78] 0x00007fff0f482a8a                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00010890 PeekMessageW+00000250
[ 79] 0x00007fff0f486283                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00025219 GetMessageA+00000243
[ 80] 0x00007fff0f48622f                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00025135 GetMessageA+00000159
[ 81] 0x00000000fab0a26b   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00172651 UIW_ShowMenuItem+00003995
[ 82] 0x00000000fab5dce2   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00515298 UIW_SuspendAttachThreadInput+00000466
[ 83] 0x0000000100118223 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01212963 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::dispatchOne+00032291
[ 84] 0x0000000100123c95 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01260693 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00005813
[ 85] 0x0000000100123d50 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01260880 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00006000
[ 86] 0x0000000100125b75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01268597 sysq::getCondition+00004629
[ 87] 0x00000001001274ba C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01275066 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000138
[ 88] 0x00000000fd0a783d   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00161853 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00023677
[ 89] 0x00000000fd0a84aa   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00165034 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00026858
[ 90] 0x00000000fd0a0135   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00131381 mcr_process_events+00007477
[ 91] 0x00000000fd0a1a12   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00137746 mcr_process_events+00013842
[ 92] 0x0000000008078f2d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\MVMLocal.dll+00167725 mvm_server::inproc::LocalFactory::terminate+00048285
[ 93] 0x00000000fa8ef1ea   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00782826 mvm::detail::initLocalMvmHack+00000490
[ 94] 0x00000000fa8ef7a8   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00784296 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000376
[ 95] 0x00000000fa8ef9f8   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00784888 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000968
[ 96] 0x0000000140005ddd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00024029
[ 97] 0x0000000140007870 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00030832
[ 98] 0x00007fff0d1f13d2                   C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL+00005074 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000034
[ 99] 0x00007fff0f615444                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00087108 RtlUserThreadStart+00000052


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: I doubt that anyone here can help.  Call MathWorks.

Comment: More appropriately, contact the authors of the `glmnet` package.